# Top exterior product of exact sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $M,N,P$ be free $R$-modules of rank $a,a+b,b$ respectively, and that they fit into an exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to P \to 0$. Is it true that $\Lambda^{a+b}N=\Lambda^aM \otimes \Lambda^bP$? (where $\Lambda^n$ means $n$th exterior product.)

The proof I am looking at seems to only work for vector spaces, yet it claims the result to be true for all $R$-modules, it will be great if someone can provide a proof, or a counter example.

Comment: The proof for vector spaces carries over. It uses that every vector space has a basis. But if $M$, $N$ and $P$ are free $R$-modules, they also contain a basis (this is, what being free means). For general $R$-modules, this would not make sense (as it is not clear, what $a$ and $b$ should be).

Comment: the proof I am reading uses the fact that a homomorphism between 2 one dimensional vector spaces is either zero or an isomorphism, so it would not carry over, sorry for not specifying this... or perhaps there is another proof that only uses the existence of basis of vector spaces? I would be glad to see one

Comment: Doesn't it rather use that fact that, given two one-dimensional vector spaces, there exists an isomorphism between them? This would again carry over, since $\Lambda^{a+b}N$, $\Lambda^aM$ and $\Lambda^bP$ (and hence $\Lambda^aM\otimes_R\Lambda^bP$) are free $R$-modules of rank one.

Comment: Why don't you write down the proof for vector spaces? Like this, it would be easiest to see the problems you have.

Comment: Let the homomorphisms be $I: M \to N$ and $p: N \to P$. Define $f:\Lambda^a M \otimes \Lambda^b P \to \Lambda^{a+b} N$ by $f((u_1 \wedge ... \wedge u_a) \otimes (w_1 \wedge ... \wedge w_b))=i(u_1) \wedge i(u_a) \wedge p^{-1}(w_1) \wedge ... \wedge p^{-1}(w_b)$. Note that although $p^{-1}(w_k)$ are not uniquely determined, the formula for $f$ is since the values for $p^{-1}(w_k)$ differ by images of $i$. $f$ is a nonzero map between 2 one dimensional vector spaces thus an isomorphism.

Comment: @user218931 I see your point, perhaps I should have specified that I would like to see the isomorphism being canonical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$, $N$ and $P$ be free $R$-modules of rank $a$, $a+b$ and $b$ respectively. Let 
$$
0\longrightarrow M\xrightarrow\varphi N\xrightarrow\psi P\longrightarrow 0
$$
be an exact sequence. Let $m_1,\dotsc,m_a$ be an $R$-basis of $M$ and $p_1,\dotsc,p_b$ be an $R$-basis of $P$. Let $n_i:= \varphi(m_i)$ for $i=1,\dotsc,a$ and choose $n_{a+i}\in \psi^{-1}(p_i)$ for $i=1,\dotsc,b$. We claim that $n_1,\dotsc,n_{a+b}$ is an $R$-basis of $N$.

They generate: Let $x\in N$ be arbitrary. Write $\psi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^b \lambda_{a+i}p_i$ for some $\lambda_{a+i}\in R$. Then
$$
\psi\left(x - \sum_{i=1}^b \lambda_{a+i} n_{a+i}\right) = \psi(x) - \sum_{i=1}^b \lambda_{a+i}p_{i} = 0,
$$
i. e. $x- \sum_{i=1}^b\lambda_{a+i}n_{a+i}\in \ker\psi = {\rm im}\varphi$. Hence, there exist $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_a\in R$ with $x- \sum_{i=1}^b\lambda_{a+i}n_{a+i} = \sum_{i=1}^a\lambda_i n_i$. This shows
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^a\lambda_in_i + \sum_{i=1}^b \lambda_{a+i} n_{a+i} = \sum_{i=1}^{a+b}\lambda_i n_i.
$$
$R$-linear independency: Let $\lambda_i\in R$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{a+b} \lambda_in_i = 0$. Then
$$
0 = \psi\left(\sum_{i=1}^{a+b}\lambda_in_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{a+b} \lambda_i \psi(n_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{b}\lambda_{a+i}p_i
$$
and hence $\lambda_{a+1}=\dotsb=\lambda_{a+b} = 0$ since $p_1,\dotsc,p_b$ are $R$-linearly independent. Hence, we have
$$
0 = \varphi\left(\sum_{i=1}^a\lambda_im_i\right),
$$
i. e. $\sum_{i=1}^a\lambda_im_i = 0$ since $\varphi$ is injective. Therefore $\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_a=0$ since $m_1,\dotsc,m_a$ are $R$-linearly independent.

This shows that $n_1,\dotsc,n_{a+b}$ is indeed an $R$-basis of $N$.

Now, notice that $n_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge n_{a+b}$ is an $R$-basis of $\Lambda^{a+b}N$, $m_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge m_a$ is an $R$-basis of $\Lambda^aM$ and $p_1\wedge\dotsb \wedge p_b$ is an $R$-basis of $\Lambda^bP$. We define
$$
f\colon \Lambda^{a+b}N\longrightarrow \Lambda^aM\otimes_R\Lambda^bP
$$
by $f(n_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge n_{a+b}):= m_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge m_a \otimes p_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge p_b$ (which is an $R$-basis of $\Lambda^aM\otimes_R\Lambda^bP$).

Since $f$ maps a basis to a basis, it has to be an isomorphism. (You could also show, that the inverse $f^{-1}\colon \Lambda^aM\otimes_R\Lambda^bP \rightarrow \Lambda^{a+b}N$, given by $f^{-1}(m_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge m_a \otimes p_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge p_b) = n_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge n_{a+b}$ is well-defined).

Comment: Very detailed solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 8):

I think these problems should be tackled by the universal property of exterior powers and then your question will have a natural answer even if it were just projective modules (not necessarily free) and even for vector bundles (when the sequence may no longer split). Giving an $R$-module  homomorphism $\wedge^r M\to N$ where $M, N$ are $R$-modules is equivalent to giving an alternating multilinear map $M\times\cdots\times M=M^r\to N$ (product of $M$, $r$ times). So, given an exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to P\to 0$, for any $a,b$ one gets an alternating multilinear map $M^a\times N^b\to\wedge^{a+b} N$ in the obvious manner. If $M$ is a rank $a$ vector bundle (free module, projective module), one easily checks that this map factors through $M^a\times P^b\to \wedge^{a+b} N$ and thus a bilinear map $\wedge^aM\times \wedge^b P\to \wedge^{a+b}N$. The rest is just local checking what these maps are.

Comment: very elegant and instructive approach. +1